How do i get an audio from speaker output? (Python) (Linux)
I am trying to make an audio visualizer control panel for my light up ram, but I can't find much on how to make it work. I tried soundcard, another Python library, but it does not get audio from output sources. I need the audio output from the audio my graphics card is sending to my monitor, so I can make an equalizer of sorts. My OS is Debian 12 Stable.
Here's my current code, it's just a thing that changes colors through OpenRGB-python, and displays an estimate of what it would look like, and displays it on the ram:
import pygame
from openrgb import OpenRGBClient
from openrgb.utils import RGBColor, ZoneType,DeviceType
import time
import random
import math

cli = OpenRGBClient()

# finding a linear zone

zone = cli.get_devices_by_type(DeviceType.DRAM)

# dividing the color spectrum by number of LEDs in the zone
step = int(360/len(zone[0].zones[0].colors))
# Setting the zones colors to the entire spectrum of the rainbow
s = 0
huee = 0
nexthue = 50
transition = 0
sine = 0
    

display = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,720),flags=0,display=2,vsync=pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
offset = 1
size = display.get_size()
framerate = 3
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
dt = 0
speed = 1
frametime = 0
frames = 0
while True:
    for v in pygame.event.get():
        pass
    display.fill((0,0,0))
    for dimm, stick in enumerate(zone):
        stickcolor = pygame.surface.Surface((1,10))
        cols = []
        for col in range(10):
            stickcolor.set_at((0,col),(cols[col].red,cols[col].green,cols[col].blue))
        stick.set_colors(cols,fast=True)
        display.blit(pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.transform.scale(stickcolor,(480 / 10,480 / 24)),(480 / 10,480)) ,(dimm * (48),0))
    offset += (dt * speed) * 1
    dt = clock.tick(120) * 0.001
    pygame.display.update()

I tried only soundcard as that's all I could find. I thought it would allow me to get the audio from the output of the monitor.

Have you tried capturing audio from the "Stereo Mix" recording device?

I've looked into this before too but there really doesn't seem to be much. One of the solutions, though really stupid, would be to download and use Virtual input sources (smth like Soundflower). You might find something else here though: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55143976 & https://stackoverflow.com/q/53902065
Good luck, and if you find a solution let me know!

I cant install pyaudio because it just errors with something about it not being able to compile

@lemon8de Isn't that a Windows thing? I'm using Debian, so I'm not sure it will work.
